# PHP meaning of '//'

Tags: php, python, precision, division

I've been converting some code from other languages (that are using algorithms) and adding them into PHP to some class code.

I came across some code that did the following line: (Python)

```
decNumber = decNumber // 2
```

I thought that it meant divide by two, but the outcome of adding this to my code was not as expected.

If this doesn't mean `/2` in PHP form then is there a PHP equivalent for this?

Comment: In python if `3/10` is calculated it returns the ans `3.3333333...` But in python if we use `3//10` it will return just 3 to you. It rounds up after dividing.

Comment: Would the PHP equivalent be `ceil`? - Ceil just rounds upwards like `3.01 = 4` @abhishekbagul

Comment: No. But floor will do. 3.01 = 3

Comment: Ah, thanks @Harikrishnan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP `//` means [single line comment](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.comments.php). The characters after `//` won't be executed.

You can use [type casting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) in PHP for achieving the same. Below code will give you integer quotient.

```
<?php
$decNumber = 3;
$decNumber = (int)($decNumber / 2) ;
echo $decNumber;
?>
```

Output

`1`

Comment: I understand that in PHP, but in Python it's used in arithmetic and wondering if there is a PHP equivalent.